# angular set non-checked checkbox to false in serialized data

Tags: angular, angular-template-form

I'd like for my checkbox to be initialized to false not NULL because the form will only set the checkbox value to false if it is first checked and unchecked, otherwise it stays null and i get this error.

Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Boolean'.Path 'inStock',line 1, position 84.

How do i initialize the form data to false using template forms in Angular?

```
createRegisterForm() {
this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
  partname:['', Validators.required],
  partdescription : ['', Validators.required],
  parturl: ['',null],
  sku: ['',null],
  inStock: '',
  isActive: '' 
})
```

}

```
registerPart() {
if (this.registerForm.valid) {
  this.part = Object.assign({}, this.registerForm.value);
  this.partsService.add(this.part).subscribe(() => {
    this.alertify.success('Part Registered');
  }, error => {
    this.alertify.error(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Well, initialize inStock to `false` instead of `''`.

Comment: If I initialize to false like you said, the checkbox is checked on load

Comment: No it's not: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhvmjb. Some other code, that you have not posted, does that.

Answer (score 0):

everytime you run reset method will set the from value to **null** in that case you can provide a value as default value to false like this

```
this.registerForm.reset({
  inStock: false,
  isActive: false
});
```

and you need set the initial value during creation to false instead to empty string in case you dont call the rest method wilt values like above.

```js
createRegisterForm() {
this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
  partname:['', Validators.required],
  partdescription : ['', Validators.required],
  parturl: ['',null],
  sku: ['',null],
  inStock: false,
  isActive: false 
})
}
```

check this [demo ⚡⚡](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8qhtyf) where I cover all cases where form control value can be endup null and why to fix this